# After SignInSignup login Azure B2C is routing to reset password flow only a couple of users

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

First time here. I have a website that uses azure b2c for authentication. The thing is sometimes after successful login (or so I think), users are redirected to password reset flow instead of the website. This is not the intended behavior and these are not first time users. I have users that cannot use the website at all because the issue (it loops after sucessful token validation), even after cache clearing.

I had a user that after he triggered the password reset challenge via link he was able to enter the website. But then again, logged out, logged in and then keeps appearing the password reset flow that loops.

I created a user with the sole purpose of testing the behavior with varying results, not consistent.

Question is, what methods on website code should I be looking for to fix this not intended behavior. Or if first I have to check a property or flag on azure b2c flows or it could be something specific to the user registry.

I´m more than thankful with any help that can lead me to fix this issue

Edit: Using .Net Framework 4.5 with MVC 5 c#

On an user account with the issue, after successful login, on redirect to website, claim values are coming empty. After this, the password reset flow triggers.

```
            foreach (Claim claim in ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims)
            {
                if (claim.Type.ToLower().Equals("emails"))
                    cMail = claim.Value;
                if (claim.Type.ToLower().Equals("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))
                    cObjectIdentifier = claim.Value;
            }
```

Is it possible that the user is blocked or risk flagged in azure? and if so, where do I check it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Check the behavior of your site in Chrome Icognito Mode. My guess it that you redirect users to PW reset whenever any error happens in B2C, not just the specific error code. Other than that, very hard to say since you fail to even mention which technology your site is using.

Comment: Hi. The site uses .Net Framework 4.5 with MVC 5 c#

Comment: Few things you can mention which will help to solve your issue: If you followed any of the sample please add the sample link, also what modification you have done with that sample. Mention whether you used User flow/Custom Policy, if  you used custom policy which starter pack you used and what modification you have done. If User Flow then please add the Screenshot of your configuration. Also, check the network tracer and share the errors you are getting on the browser . 

These all will help to get the answer quickly.